# _ah/warmup requests coming with hosts prefixed with app version

Tags: google-app-engine

I am using the warmup service to carry out precaching/etc. The request gets called with self.request.host being prefixed with a version of the app.

All other handler requests are coming with the expected host name for the app.

So if the app name is myapp - then all requests are called with self.request.host set to myapp.appspot.com, whereas for "_ah/warmup" call it is getting set to nnn.myapp.appspot.com.

My code is expecting the self.request.host to be always 'myapp.appspot.com'. Is this by design or am I missing something.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is by design because the warmup service is for a specific version. All other requests are going straight to your main app URL, which is just "aliased" to whatever version happens to be the default version at the time.

By the way, it is documented that you can access all deployed versions of your app by prefixing the version number to the domain name, so you should be aware that any users could access any version if they know about this, and if you haven't taken countermeasures! So you should definitely support this - it's an official feature of App Engine.

Comment: Thanks Robin. This is very useful ! What is the best way to countermeasure - (when you a non-default version is triggered). Can you call 'exit()' for instance to force a shutdown ? Thanks again.